# Metric describing difference between two proper-rigid transformations in 3D

Tags: metric-spaces, rigid-transformation

I am estimating a transformation $\hat{T} \in SE(3)$ between two 3-dimensional coordinate systems (COS) $C1, C2$. I know the exact (ground truth) transformation between the two COS, namely $T_{GT} \in SE(3)$. Any point $p$ transformed from $C1$ to $C2$ using $\hat{T}$ results in a deviation (Euclidean distance) in $C2$ from the same point transformed by $T_{GT}$.

I found an article from Huynh (Huynh, 2009, Metrics for 3D Rotations: Comparison and Analysis) which describes several metrics describing the difference between two 3D purely rotational transformations ($SO(3)$).

Is there something similar to this for two transformations in $SE(3)$?

In short: What kind of a metric should I use to describe the mismatch between two transformations in SE(3)?

Intuitively, what I am interested in are deviations (Euclidean distances) between points in $C2$ (in a volume of interest) as transformed from $C1$ to $C2$ by the estimated transformation $\hat{T}$ and the ground truth transformation $T_{GT}$.

Comment: One issue is that, unlike in $SO(3)$, a transformation in $SE(3)$ is not "dimensionless": it involves both a rotation and a translation. Suppose $T$ and $\hat T$ differ by a rotation by $1$ radian and a translation of $1$ unit. If $C_1$ is only $0.01$ units in diameter, then the translation has much more effect on $\|Tp-\hat Tp\|$ than the rotation does. The opposite is true if $C_1$ is $100$ units in diameter.

Comment: What do you mean with "$C1$ is only $0.01$ units in diameter"?Otherwise I agree with you that the question may be more difficult to answer for $SE(3)$ than for $SO(3)$. The question remains though...

Comment: I mean the appropriate scaling between the rotational and translational component of $\hat T$ depends on how big your volume of interest is.

Comment: OK. Maybe, is it valid to define a metric that considers the translational and the rotational part separately? Translational could be euclidean distance and rotational sth described by Huynh. In the end it would be necessary to combine the two again in some way.